# Comparing two arrays in C

Tags: c

so I have this code, if all of the characters from letters_guessed[] are in secret[] it returns 1, otherwise it should return 0, but the function will always evaluate as true, please help me

```
int is_word_guessed(const char secret[], const char letters_guessed[])
{       
        int x = 0;
        int secret_letters = strlen(secret);
        int guessed = strlen(letters_guessed);
        for( int  a=0; a< secret_letters;a++)
        {
                for (int i=0; i < guessed;i++)
                {
                        if ( letters_guessed[i] == secret[a])
                        {
                                x =i;
                                continue;
                        }
                }       
                if (letters_guessed[x] != secret[a])
                {
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sort and compare.

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much more efficient one

```
int is_word_guessed(const char secret[], const char letters_guessed[])
{       
    size_t secret_letters = strlen(secret);
    size_t guessed = strlen(letters_guessed);
    int a[256+128] = {0};
    for(size_t i = 0; i < secret_letters ; i++) a[secret[i]+128] = 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < guessed; i++) 
        if( !a[letters_guessed[i]+128])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Here you only need to iterate `O(n+m)` time. Previous one was `O(n*m)` time complexity in worst case. (`n`: string length of guessed word `m`: string length of secret)

And yes you had the logic wrong. The outer loop should iterate over array and then the inner loop should check whether that letter is part of the secret word. But here the order is not considered. (Atleast you asked that ..)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to these questions are freely available on google so I want you to surf a bit more.
Here is a similar approach that might help:

```
void doLettersMatch(char userInput[], char letters[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(userInput);i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; userInput[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
           if(userInput[j] == letters[i]) {
               ++found;
               printf("success! the letters matched from the user input");
               return;
           }
       }
    }
    noMatch();
}
```